# Embedding more than one user generated image with swiftmailer

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

Am building a website that sends html emails with image embedded inline, I know Swiftmailer can embed inline images with     $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath(''))

but I develop a drag and drop Email Builder where users can design their email, include any image then send the email.
So how do i embed the images automatically with Swifmailer.
Pls. I really need help have been research for days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swift_Image::newInstance to embed an image without loading it from disk.

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#embedding-dynamic-content

```
<?php
// Create your file contents in the normal way, but don't write them to disk
$img_data = create_my_image_data();

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('My subject');

// Embed images into message and collect references
$images = [
  "image1.jpg" => $message->embed(Swift_Image::newInstance($img1_data, 'image1.jpg', 'image/jpeg')),
  "image2.jpg" => $message->embed(Swift_Image::newInstance($img2_data, 'image2.jpg', 'image/jpeg'))
];

// Replace placeholder urls with embedded image reference
// eg <img src="image1.jpg"> => <img src="cid:XXXXX">
$userHTML = str_tr($userHTML, $images);

// Set the body
$message->setBody($userHTML,
  'text/html' // Mark the content-type as HTML
);
```

The `$userHTML` variable would be the user generated HTML with image tags with placeholder urls. The embed would create the multipart data and return a reference mapped in the `$images` array to the placeholder url strings. The `str_tr` step would replace the placeholder strings with the cid:XXXX resource string.

Comment: Thanks, but the images and html are user generated so i can't use this solution, is there no way for me to embed my images automatically without having to manually edit the 'src' url? thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say Drag and Drop are you referring to Dropping files from their file system into the web browser. Or existing server files drag and drop positioning within the interface. Either way in order to use swiftmail the image content will need to be transfer to the application is some way (eg POST multipart encoded or binary upload). I imagine you are using GD or imagic (or a js resampler) to resize the email, you the output of that to embed the image.